# Android Navigation Component visits Edittext.addTextChangedListener on navigateUp

Tags: android, navigation, android-edittext, components

There is pretty strange behavior that I observe using **Navigation Component**. You can check it yourself using a debugger. Create some `Edittext` and set `addTextChangedListener` with `TextWatcher`.

Then navigate from the fragment to another fragment and navigate back using `navigateUp()`. The previous fragment is going to recreate and during that, it will visit `TextWatcher` methods: `beforeTextChanged`, `onTextChanged` and `afterTextChanged` respectively.

Whereas opening another activity and navigating back or running the fragment for the first time, does not cause visiting `TextWatcher` methods without altering `Edittext`.

Any ideas why this happen?

> Update
> I have made a sample App for demonstrating this strange behavior.
> [SampleApp](https://github.com/arch3rtemp/SimpleSampleApp)

Comment: set a breakpoint in your `TextWatcher#beforeTextChanged` and debug your app while running your repro and you should be able to trace back why it gets called for `navigateUp`

Comment: It gets called `navigateUp` because I call it when I navigate back from the second fragment. I just cannot debug this behavior. I've even made a simple sample app demonstrating it.